# The order of categories in refinement panel

Tags: 2010, refinement-panel

How can I change the order of categories in the refinement panel? Right now I have job title before organization, but I'd like to have organization first. Changing the order in the XML file does not help.

Comment: Start by adding the version of SharePoint you are using as a tag on the question. Makes it way easier to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Every `<category>` tag has these properties:

`SortBy="Frequency"`

`SortDirection="Descending"`

You can change them by editing refinement web part's xml :)

Comment: Gintas K, I'm talking about the order of categories, not the filter items inside each category. Any idea?

Comment: Problem solved. Had some misunderstanding in my xml file.